# SQL Statement with 3 conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have two tables:

```
Name    Forename   CostCentre
Max      Meier       11111
Paul     Peters      22222
Kai      Green       11111

CostCentre   departmentCostCentre
11111                 HR
22222                 IT
```

Besides this I have a Searchfield and a combobox for the cost centre.

> If I enter "a" in the searchfield and "11111" in cost centre, I'll get all records...

But I just want to get Max and Kai. Here's my SQL statement:

```
SELECT tbl_Employee.Name, tbl_Employee.Forename, tbl_Employee.CostCentre, tbl_Department.Department
FROM tbl_DepartmentINNER JOIN tbl_EmployeeON tbl_Department.CostCentre= tbl_Employee.CostCentre
WHERE tbl_Employee.Name Like "*a*" OR tbl_Employee.Forename Like "*a*"AND tbl_Mitarbeiter.CostCentre=44444;
```

I really don't know where's the error.... If I delete the name or forename condition it works fine, but with both I get weird results...

Comment: In your sample, all three of them have `Name`s containing `a`, so all three should be returned. That being said, your sample data appears to be the wrong way around (with values that don't look like forenames in the `forename` column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the cost centre condition to *always* apply and for the name conditions to apply to either name, then you need to use parenthesis:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Employee
WHERE (tbl_Employee.Name Like 'a' Or
      tbl_Employee.Forename Like 'a') And
      tbl_Employee.CostCentre=22222;
```

Otherwise, `And` binds more closely than `Or` and you're instead saying that *either* the `Name` condition must match *or* that both the `Forename` and `CostCentre` conditions must match.

Your question did already include some parentheses in your code which I've removed. I'm not sure what they related to.

---

Based on updated query:

```
SELECT tbl_Employee.Name, tbl_Employee.Forename, tbl_Employee.CostCentre, tbl_Department.Department
FROM tbl_DepartmentINNER JOIN tbl_EmployeeON tbl_Department.CostCentre= tbl_Employee.CostCentre
WHERE
   (
      tbl_Employee.Name Like "*a*"
      OR
      tbl_Employee.Forename Like "*a*"
   )
   AND
   tbl_Mitarbeiter.CostCentre=44444;
```

Comment: @okaisan1 - still seems to be the same problem - when you have a combination of `OR`s and `AND`s without using `()` parenthesis, the `AND`s bind more tightly than the `OR`s so without `()`s, you're asking for "anything that matches `Name`" OR "anything that matches `Forename` and matches `CostCentre`"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbl_Employee
WHERE
    tbl_Employee.Name LIKE '%a%'
    AND tbl_Employee.CostCentre = 11111;
```